# Cannot see Azure DB tables when using Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure-sql-database

I'm new to Azure and I'm trying to connect to our Azure DB using Visual Studio.

I can connect to the DB fine, but when I expand the DB I cannot see any DB Objects.  See the image below.  I've Googled the issue but cannot find where anyone has replicated this issue, so I accept I'm likely doing something wrong!

I can query the DB fine and it will return results.

[image: Azure DB no objects]

Answer (score 0):

To connect the visual studio to azure database and view the tables of database in visual studio follow the following steps:

1. Open your project in visual studio, Click on server explorer

[image]

2. Then click on SQL server Object explorer

[image]

3. Then click on Add SQL Server

[image]

4. Then expand Azure, click on your mail id and select subscription.

[image]

5. Then it will show all databases present in your subscription, select
   your database I will fetch all information expect password, provide
   your password and click on connect.

[image]

It will show all your databases tables from azure database

[image]

You can refer to this Document for more information: [Work with Visual Studio to connect to SQL Databases in Azure.](https://www.sqlshack.com/working-with-visual-studio-and-sql-azure-databases/)